# Prevent Git from Deleting Ignored Files

Tags: git, heroku, git-branch

I have a master branch for local development and a heroku branch to deploy to heroku. I have a conf file that I ignore and don't check into master cause it's private, but it's not ignored in the heroku branch and it's been added to the repo because the heroku server needs it to work.

Problem: I noticed that when I did git checkout from master to heroku, it deleted my conf file from master. The heroku conf file must've just automatically overwritten the same file on master and since that file was being ignored, git did not warn me that I had uncommitted changes, which I did... shucks...

How do I prevent this sort of thing from happening? Is there a way to get a warning about it, or perhaps I should tweak the way I'm managing things.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to tweaking the way you manage things, I'd recommend setting up environmental variables for all your private config. Heroku supports them and they greatly simplify deployment and repository setup for open source projects (see http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to change your workflow a bit, it sounds like you SHOULD be checking in that configuration file locally. I have similar needs, and I do something similar:

```
Workflow:
Master -> Work -> Heroku
```

In this case, you would check the configuration file into `Work`, along with any other private files. To commit, you need to move to master and user `cherry-pick` on work with all commits that aren't private. I use all commits that don't start with `NOCOMMIT:` and build that into a script I call `pull-work.sh`

In this way, you don't break the model of `DVCS` with config files that might as well be versioned by separated from the remote repository.

Here's `pull-work.sh`. This was developed by another SO user on one of my similar, albeit different enough, questions.

```
#!/bin/sh

BRANCH=`git branch | grep ^\\* | cut -d' ' -f2`
if [ $BRANCH != "master" ]; then
  echo "$0: Current branch is not master"
  exit 1
fi

git log --pretty=oneline work...master | grep -v -E '(NOCOMMIT|DEBUG):' | cut -d' ' -f1 | tac | xargs -l git cherry-pick
```

Comment: +1 but a link back to the question you mentioned would be nice